# What is a dyad?

Tags: graph-theory

I often hear the term 'dyad' in graph theory, but what does it mean? Suppose I have a graph $G=(V,E)$ then what are the dyads in this graphs?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, a dyad is just an induced subgraph of order $2$, i.e., a pair of vertices, together with any and all edges between them.

Answer (score 0):

SubGraph with two vertices together with the edge.